# How get the private key using web3js?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

is it possible to get the private key of ethereum wallet using web3js?

I want to encrypt data using the ethererum keys?

Comment: Yes, if you have the password.

Comment: how to do with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have the password.

Here is a NodeJS script (call it RecoverPrivateKey.js):

```
let fs = require("fs");
let keythereum = require("keythereum");

let address = process.argv[2];
let datadir = process.argv[3];
let pw_file = process.argv[4];

let keyObject  = keythereum.importFromFile(address, datadir);
let privateKey = keythereum.recover(fs.readFileSync(pw_file).toString(), keyObject);
console.log("0x" + privateKey.toString("hex"));
```

Usage example (from command-line):

```
node ./RecoverPrivateKey.js 01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef ./ ./password.txt
```

Comment: You can retrieve the `address` argument from the `id` field inside the key-file, or from the name of the key-file (its suffix).

Comment: isn't possible using web3js?

Comment: @maroodb: What difference would that make?

Comment: I need to know all possible ways ;)